# Adding a page load string in footer of ASP.NET masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I would like to add a label in the footer of my ASP.NET application that shows my users how long each page took to load. In my `site.master` page I currently have:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
   {
    public Stopwatch pageLoadTime = new Stopwatch();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pageLoadTime.Start();

        //Other stuff here

        pageLoadTime.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = pageLoadTime.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value. 
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);

        PageLoadTimeLabel.Text = "Page loaded in " + elapsedTime;
    }
```

But this isn't giving me a "true" page load time, even if a page take 5 seconds to load it returns 0.1 seconds. So I moved the end code to the `Page_LoadComplete` section, but this cannot update the label it seems.

Any pointers? I know I can use firebug etc, but I would like my users to have easy access to this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in the `global.asax`:

```
private DateTime start_time

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    start_time = DateTime.Now;
}
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var duration = DateTime.Now - start_time;
    Response.Write("...");
}
```

Or write it to a session and read in your master page.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Linus I have created this which does what I want:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Context.Items["loadstarttime"] = DateTime.Now;
}
```

and then

```
public void Application_EndRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime end = (DateTime)Context.Items["loadstarttime"];
    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - end;

    // Format and display the TimeSpan value. 
    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);

    Response.Write("<div style='text-align: center' class='thesmallprint'>Page loaded in: " + elapsedTime + "</div>");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Page.LoadComplete can help you. If you make start the timer in Page_Load event handler and stop it in the LoadComplete event handler, then you might get the actual time.